# Popup screen when using a stylus in blender grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

In Blender Grease Pencil, when I use a stylus on my touchscreen computer, a pop up screen sometimes appears at the location of the stylus. Is there any way to adjust the settings so the popup screen stops appearing? (The picture below is the popup screen). [image]

Comment: This isn’t called a pop-up screen, it’s called a tool tip. They are common in all PC UI. Not sure if there’s a way to turn them off in Blender, but if there is, that’s what you need to look for in Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: get rid of the context menu**

Perhaps you don't mean the tooltip, but the entire context menu. Some Wacom pens have a 'press and hold' function to emulate right clicking. [You can disable that in your OS settings](https://support.wacom.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500006338262-The-pen-right-clicks-when-pressing-down-what-do-I-do-).

Or you can disable the context menu in Blender. Go to `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Keymap`, unfold `Grease Pencil`, unfold `Grease Pencil Stroke Paint Mode` and uncheck `Draw Context Menu`.

[image: Preferences GP Stroke Paint Mode]

But as you can see, there are several other modes – you have to disable the right mouse in them too.

**Original answer:**

In the preferences you can disable tooltips.

Go to `Edit` -> `Preferences...` -> `Interface` tab and disable `User Tooltips`.

[image: Preferences Interface]

When you occasionally want to see a tooltip, you can hold `Alt` when hovering over an item.

Comment: After disabling the User Tooltips in the Display section, the popup screen still appears. For more context, when I hold my stylus down on my touchscreen and have little to no movement, the pop-up screen appears. This makes it complicated to draw because when I am trying to draw an incredibly small line by holding down the stylus on the touchscreen, it contains very little movement of the stylus, so the pop up screen will appear.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with a 'press and hold' function of your stylus (which emulates a mouse right click). I've updated my answer.